# My laptop takes too long time to shutdown or hibernate

Tags: windows-8.1, shutdown, hibernate, lenovo-laptop

I've recently encountered a problem which is my notebook, Lenovo Ideapad z500 with Windows 8.1 pro, takes too long time to shutdown or hibernate. When I click on shutdown item, the LCD is powered off soon but my notebook takes about 10-15min to shutdown.

Comment: i've encountered this problem once due to non-responding DNS setting on windows 7 ... if that's not the case [which is most likely ;) ] ..this may help ..http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/504167/windows-8-super-slow-shutdown/

Comment: What have you tried or researched? Are there any error messages or events in the event viewer? Have all updates been installed for Lenovo and Windows?

Comment: install the WPT (http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4847.install-the-windows-performance-toolkit-wpt.aspx) and follow my guide: http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=158252 Upload the generated ETL files.